# Why can't pass object reference to a template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, reference

Here's my [code](https://godbolt.org/z/K614a6r8c):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct LogParamScaler
{
};

template <LogParamScaler &T>
struct QRange {
    
};

int main()
{
    LogParamScaler mLogParamScaler;
    QRange<mLogParamScaler> qRange;
}
```

but it says to me *& mLogParamScaler' is not a valid template argument of type 'LogParamScaler&' because 'mLogParamScaler' has no linkage*

I'm on c++11, can't pass by reference? Tried also with pointer, but seems I can't as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct LogParamScaler
{
};

template <LogParamScaler *T>
struct QRange {
    
};

int main()
{
    LogParamScaler mLogParamScaler;
    QRange<&mLogParamScaler> qRange;
}
```

What's the way to do it using templates? I must use them because `QRange<mLogParamScaler>` will be used as "type" for another object/template, i.e. `createObject<QRange<mLogParamScaler>>`.

Comment: A template argument of reference type cannot come from an automatic variable. It must be a variable with static storage duration. Same thing about pointer template arguments.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit another alternative? tried with member on CTOR, but somethings like this seems illegal: `createObject<QRange{mParamScalerRes}>`

Comment: is there a reason why you need a reference type for the template argument?

Comment: @bolov pass to a method which take in input a template, as write above `createObject<QRange{mParamScalerRes}>`. I can also pass "by value" if that's possible, no need a reference. But must be a template (to chain `createObject<>`)

Comment: Can you modify `QRange` and `createObject`? Because if you can, then the answer still remains: Why do you need the template argument to be a reference as oposed to value or even a type template?

Comment: @bolov: I can edit QRange, not createObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are instantiated at compile time. So every argument needs to be "known" at compile time. For non-type template parameters this means every argument must have [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (simple terms: the variable passed must be alive for the entire duration of the program).

In C++11 you can pass a global variable:

```
struct LogParamScaler {};

template <LogParamScaler &T>
struct QRange {};

LogParamScaler gLogParamScaler;

int main()
{
    QRange<gLogParamScaler> gRange;
}
```

Since C++17 you can also pass a local variable with static storage duration:

```
struct LogParamScaler {};

template <LogParamScaler &T>
struct QRange {};

int main()
{
    static LogParamScaler mLogParamScaler;
    QRange<mLogParamScaler> qRange;

}
```

If you don't need the template parameter to be a reference type you can have this since C++20:

```
struct LogParamScaler {};

template <LogParamScaler T>
struct QRange {};


int main()
{
    QRange<LogParamScaler{}> qRange;
}
```

Comment: @bolow while doing it using "global variable", inheritance of passed object by reference is not permitted for obvious reasons: godbolt.org/z/W35nfYz8G Is there a way to do this?